# Continuity of a function $f(x)=\begin{cases} -1, & x<0 \\ b, & x=0 \\ +1, & x>0 \end{cases}$

Tags: continuity

This is a homework problem so I would prefer hints to answers.

$b \in \mathbb{R} $

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1, & x<0 \\
 b, & x=0 \\
+1, & x>0
\end{cases}$

Does a number b exist so that $f(x)$ is continous?

I believe $f(x)$to be continuous for $x>0$ and $x<0$ due to the fact that if i made the function $g(x)= 1 $ $\forall x > 0$ it would be continous, same for  -1. but I'm not sure how to go about it for $x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- You should be able to conclude from observing $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)$

Comment: I was going to post exactly this but you're faster :(

Comment: So this means that it is discontinous in $x=0$? if I understand correctly

Comment: that's correct.